# Get data into excel sheet from 2 tables

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel

i have two tables Brands and products. Each brand will have multiple no of products. I need to generate an excel sheets which will be like it prints the Brand Details first and under each brand there should be products that are related to that brand. The sql query should return all the data like that and then i need to show them in excel accordingly.

[image]

for id in tblListing we have to print as a parent row and then from tblProductstoListings we get the products for that listings and then show all the details of products for that listings same for all the listings in tblListing  table

Comment: Post your code you have so far, and post your table structures

Comment: where is the brands table?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way: You can load your data into a **DataSet**, do needed calculations and changes on it and after that try with `dyour_ataset.writeXML("filename.xlsx")` for importing it to excel